# How to convert hash_map<string, string> to hash_map<wstring, wstring> using the std::transform algorithm?

Tags: c++

I know it is supposed to be easy, but I just fail to get rid of the compilation errors. Here is my code:

```
template<class C>
struct basic_field_type_map : public hash_map<basic_string<C>, basic_string<C>>
{
};

typedef basic_field_type_map<char> field_type_map;
typedef basic_field_type_map<wchar_t> wfield_type_map;

wfield_type_map::value_type to_wfield_type_map_value(field_type_map::const_reference src)
{
  return wfield_type_map::value_type(to_wstring(src.first), to_wstring(src.second));
}

wfield_type_map to_wfield_type_map(const field_type_map& m)
{
  wfield_type_map res;
  transform(m.begin(), m.end(), res.begin(), to_wfield_type_map_value);
  return res;
}
```

Where `to_wstring` has the following signature:

```
wstring to_wstring(const string& s)
```

Compiling the code gives me the following errors:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(260): error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=wchar_t,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<wchar_t>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(707): could be 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=wchar_t,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<wchar_t>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(761): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=wchar_t,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<wchar_t>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(766): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(const _Elem *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=wchar_t,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<wchar_t>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(771): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(_Elem)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=wchar_t,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<wchar_t>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>, const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=wchar_t,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<wchar_t>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(259) : while compiling class template member function 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::operator =(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>,
1>              _Ty2=std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>
1>          ]
1>          z:\dev\internal\vedtool\defs.h(34) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>,
1>              _Ty2=std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>
1>          ]
Build has been canceled.
```

I am using VS2010.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keytype in a map is `const`, you can't assign to it, which is what `std::transform` does; the loop looks something like this:

```
for(; first != last; ++first, ++dest)
  *dest = func(*first);  // assignment of key-value pair here
```

Note that there is an even bigger problem: You `res` map doesn't even have the space to hold all the stuff from the `field_type_map`! You're invoking undefined behaviour here by just writing past the end.

Your best bet is to manually `insert` each new pair with `for_each`:

```
std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(),
    [&](field_type_map::value_type const& p){
      res.insert(to_wfield_type_map_value(p));
    });
```

Comment: First of all, I admit being stupid. Next, since C++ has anonymous functions?

Comment: Is there a pipeline solution, where I call `transform(m.begin(), m.end(), insert_iterator(res), func)`?

Comment: @mark: Not with an obsolete `hash_map`, since it doesn't have a suitable `insert` function. You can do that with `unordered_map`, though.

Comment: I have returned to c++ after about 6 years of absence. The landscape has changed since then, that's for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `res.begin()` as the output argument for `transform`, for two reasons:

- the map is empty, so `begin()` isn't a valid iterator, and
- map elements can't be reassigned.

One possibility is to replace the obsolete STL `hash_map` with `unordered_map`; then you can use a `std::insert_iterator` to insert values:

```
transform(m.begin(), m.end(), 
          inserter(res, res.end()), 
          to_wfield_type_map_value);
```

If you really want to use `hash_map` for some reason, then this won't work, since `hash_map` doesn't have the two-argument `insert` function that `insert_iterator` uses. As far as I can see, STL doesn't have a suitable inserter, but you could provide your own:

```
template <typename Container>
class hash_insert_iterator {
public:
    hash_insert_iterator(Container & c) : container(&c) {}

    hash_insert_iterator & 
    operator=(typename Container::value_type const & value) {
        container->insert(value);
        return *this;
    }
    hash_insert_iterator & operator*() {return *this;}
    hash_insert_iterator & operator++() {return *this;}
    hash_insert_iterator & operator++(int) {return *this;}

private:
    Container * container;
};

template <typename Container>
hash_insert_iterator<Container> hash_inserter(Container & c) {
    return hash_insert_iterator<Container>(c);
}
```

Alternatively, it might be simpler to insert directly, rather than using `transform`:

```
for (auto const & value : m) {
    res.insert(to_wfield_type_map_value(m));
}
```

or some equivalent `for` or `for_each` construct, if your compiler doesn't support range-based `for` loops.

Comment: Note that MSVC10 doesn't support range-based `for`.

Comment: @Xeo: I didn't know that. Anyway, other iteration methods are available.